# How to sum NSNumber array in Swift?

Tags: swift

How to sum NSNumber array in Swift? I'm getting this error when I use `.reduce`. any other way to sum the NSNumber array?

> Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)

```
var record = [Record]()
var incomeFilter: [Record] = []

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
formatter.currencySymbol = "¥"
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

incomeFilter = record.filter { $0.recordtype!.contains("Income") && $0.createdAt! == recordItem.createdAt!}
let incomeSumArray = incomeFilter.map{formatter.number(from: $0.amount!) ?? 0.00}.reduce(0, +)
//Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)
print(incomeSumArray)

//result without .reduce
//[9.99, 6.58, 7777.77]
```

Comment: [Once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349698/is-there-any-way-to-increase-the-number-limit-of-double-type-in-swift/47349958#47349958), why don't you **first** sum up the `Double` values and **then** use the number formatter and 
I explained the error message in my answer yesterday

Comment: I think I can't sum the double first, because some string have separator "," , so if I sum the `double` first, the number which above 1,000 will get nil. The separator break the string to double conversion routine. @vadian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is using `?? 0` with an optional of type `NSNumber`. You always need the same type when nil-coalescing. You have to convert `NSNumber` to a numeric value (`double`) first:

```
let incomeSum = incomeFilter
    .map {
        formatter.number(from: $0.amount!)?.doubleValue ?? 0
     }
    .reduce(0, +)
```

or

```
let incomeSum = incomeFilter
    .map {
        guard
           let amountString = $0.amount,
           let number = formatter.number(from: amountString)
        else {
           return 0
        }

        return number.doubleValue
     }
    .reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the `incomeFilter` to be an array of doubles (`incomeFilter.map{formatter.number(from: $0.amount!) ?? 0.00}`) before reducing it:

```
let incomeSumArray = incomeFilter.map {
        formatter.number(from: $0.amount!) ?? 0.00
    }.map {
        $0.doubleValue
    }.reduce(0, +)
```